# ¿Actualizar la vista en Angular 5?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

Estoy usando un metodo que me borra los archivos de la base de datos pinchando en la papelera cuando pincho me los borra pero en la vista no se me actualiza si no hago f5 en el navegador como podría hacer esto sin tener que actualizar la pagina

```
import { Component,DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {LoginService} from '../api/login/login.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-main',
templateUrl: './main.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
providers:[LoginService]
})
export class MainComponent implements DoCheck {

public archivo; 

constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
public _servicio:LoginService) { 


}

borrar(archivo){


console.log(archivo);

this._servicio.borrararchivos(archivo).subscribe(data => {

}, error => {

console.log('error');

});



 }
```

aqui esta mi aplicacion como veis me borra el objeto pero no se actualiza ni me lo borra en la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi servicio es el siguiente

```
 borrararchivos(id): Observable<any>{

 const url = `http://localhost/api/public/delete/${id}`;


 let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token',this.token);

 return this._http.delete(url,{headers:headers});

 }
```

Comment: Tenes que borrar el "archivo" de tu vista ( vaciar la variable)

Comment: ¿como ago eso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que muestras, tienes en tu componente una variable archivo que es la que se muestra en la vista, entonces con esto seria suficiente:

```
borrar(archivo){
  console.log(archivo);
  this._servicio.borrararchivos(archivo).subscribe(data => {
    this.archivo = null; 
// Haces null la variable de tu archivo, también puede ser {} (Objeto vació)
  }, error => {
    console.log('error');
  });

}
```

> Recuerda que `this.archivo = null;`, hace referencia a la variable archivo en tu component, no la que te llega como parámetro ya que en un futuro podrías tener una lista de elementos y tendrías que eliminar el elemento (llamado archivo aquí) de dentro de la lista del component.

---

Recuerda que Angular vincula tus variables directamente a la vista y refleja sus cambios de forma automática, por la tanto siempre que modifiques tus variables esto se va a ver reflejado en la vista y no tenes que hacer `F5`.

Comment: funciona muchas graciasss !!!!!!!!!!